# Can PuLP use MIP-solvers without writing a *-pulp.lp file?

Tags: python, pulp

I am using [PuLP](https://projects.coin-or.org/PuLP) to describe my Mixed Integer Problem (MIP) and solve this problem using the CBC-solver. PuLP writes this problem to a *-pulp.lp file, which is then subsequently be solved via the command line solver using CBC. In my overall approach I need to solve over 1M (mostly small) MIPs. Writing these files to disk leads to performance issues. I assume that when the problem file is not written to disk, the overall performance would increase.

Are there ways to avoid this writing to disk?

Comment: Pulp doesn't always write files but the default solver cbc doesn't have a non-command line interface. The Gurobi solver for instance uses the gurobi python interface. If you want to avoid file writes and still use CBC you can try using a ram disk. I guess the best way would be to rewrite the COIN_CMD solver so that it can use in memory files. I would be happy to accept a pr.

Comment: @StuartMitchell Isn't it possible to just call the `.solve()` method on the problem object without ever using the `.writeLP()` method? I'm assuming as you've suggested the files have to be written and then get read by the CBC solver that this write/read happens under the hood somewhere if not called explicitly?

Comment: @StuartMitchell, thanks for your reply. I already tried the ram disk, but this did not lead to a huge performance improvement. I will go forward in several parallel tracks. I will request a Gurobi evaluative license. Furthermore I will try to implement a version Julia (JuMP). Would using the PYGLPK in PuLP be an option, as I do not see a ` .writeLP() `?